# Bind Function to QR-Code or work as a submit-button blazor

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I'm doing a web app with Blazor. I have to scan many barcodes in and after that I want to scan a QR-Code which works as a submit button. When I scanned it, a XML file should be created with the elements in my List.

I just don't know how to bind a function to my QR-Code. It's a static QR-code like an image, so it should just work as a submit button. So when I scan the QR-Code it should generate a xml file.

Here is my Code:

```
enter code here
@inject IJSRuntime js
@using System.Xml;
@using System.Xml.Linq;
@using System.Xml.Serialization;
@page "/"
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.BarcodeGenerator
<h1>Kitted Materials</h1>
<form method="post" id="scan">
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="auftrag">
        <p class="subtitles">Auftragsnummer</p>
        <input type="text" name="vsNo" id="vsNo" @bind="vsNo" 
         class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="LSNummer">
        <p class="subtitles">LE-Nummer</p>
        <input id="LeNumber" @bind="LeNumber" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" 
         @onkeydown="addToTable" />
    </div>
    <div class="QR-Code" id="qrcode">
        <p class="subtitles">QR-SUBMIT</p>
        <img src="img/qrcode.png" alt="" 
         @onkeydown="generateXml" Width="200" Height="150" />
    </div>
    <div class="List">
        <p class="subtitles">Aktueller Auftrag: @vsNo </p>
        <table id="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="header">LE-Nummer</th>
                    <th class="header">LE-Nummer</th>
                </tr>
                @{
                    for (int i = 0; i < todos.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            @:<tr>
                                <td>@todos[i]</td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                <td>@todos[i]</td>
                            @:</tr>
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
@code{


private class Material { public string Number { get; set; } }
private List<string> todos = new List<string>();
private string LeNumber;
private string vsNo;

private async void addToTable()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LeNumber))
    {
        if (todos.Contains(LeNumber))
        {
            LeNumber = null;
            await TurnRed("table");
            await Focus("LeNumber");

        }
        else
        {

            todos.Add(LeNumber);
            LeNumber = null;
            await Focus("LeNumber");
            await TurnNormal("table");
        }

    }
}

private async void generateXml()
{
    XDocument xml = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XElement("MaterialKits",
            new XElement("batch", vsNo),
                new XElement("MaterialList",
                from le in todos
                select
                new XElement("InventoryItem", new 
                XAttribute("Action", ""),
                new XElement("Identifier", le),
                new XElement("Quantity", 1.0)
                )
               )
             )
        );
    xml.Save(@"D:\Test\xml");



}

public async Task Focus(string elementId)
{
    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("focusElement", elementId);
}

public async Task TurnRed(string elementId)
{
    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("trunRed", elementId);
}

public async Task TurnNormal(string elementId)
{
    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("trunNormal", elementId);
}
}
```